# A countable set in the finite complement topology is first and second countable

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the following assertions about a set $X$ in the finite complement topology.

If $X$ is countable then $X$ is first countable.

If $X$ is countable then $X$ is second countable.

Indeed the converse directions hold as well but I have shown these parts.

For the first assertion, the best I could come up given a fixed $x \in X$, the collection of all finite intersections of {{$y$}$^{c}$ : $y$ $\neq$ $x \in X$}. But I don't think this set is countable in the first place. How can I construct countable local bases and countable bases to prove these assertions?

Comment: The family $\mathscr{A}=\big\{X\setminus\{y\}:y\in X\setminus\{x\}\big\}$ is definitely countable: it has one member for each $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, which is certainly a countable set, since $X$ is. However, it’s not a base at $x$: if $y$ and $z$ are distinct points different from $x$, then $X\setminus\{y,z\}$ is an open nbhd of $x$ that doesn’t contain any member of $\mathscr{A}$. However, first countability will follow automatically from second countability, so you should simply prove that the topology is countable. Remember, a countable set has only countably many finite subsets.

Comment: Why does a countable set have only countably many finite sets? Also, the book I got this problem from states the two qyestions as separate problems. So I'm wondering how I can find an explicit form of a countable local basis.

Comment: Since there are only countably many open sets altogether, the family of all open nbhds of a point is a countable local base at that point. Specifically, $$\{U\subseteq X:x\in U\text{ and }X\setminus U\text{ is finite}\}$$ is a countable local base at $x$. That a countable set has only countably many finite subsets is a standard basic fact about cardinality.

Comment: That fills the gap in my knowledge thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a countable set in the finite complement topology, the topology itself consists of countably many sets (namely, the cofinite sets and the empty set). This makes the space automatically first and second countable.

Comment: why does the topology itself consist of countably many sets?